# How to override back button in salesforce1 in IOS?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, ios

I am loading a canvas app on a VF page from a custom button. The flow is :
button click from detail page -> Validation page -> Vf page with canvas app.

From vf page with canvas, whenever I press back button in SF1 ios or physical back button on android phone, I want to redirect back to detail page instead of validation page. Is there any way to override back functionality on SF1.?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a description of [sforce.one navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) functions

You need to use the `navigateToURL(​url​[, isredirect])` function
what you need to do:
on the validation page you need to place the following script:

```
if (typeof sforce !== 'undefined') {
    sforce.one.navigateToURL(yourUrl, true);
}
```

The main point is to use the second argument in the navigateToUrl call.

The salesforce doc says the following:

> isredirect is optional and defaults to false. Set it to true to indicate that the new URL should replace the current one in the
>   navigation history.

So, when you go back to the detail page, the SF1 history will ignore the validation page